# how to update a view in postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, drupal-6, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot update view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151566/cannot-update-view)

My site was developing using Drupal version 6 and db is `PostgreSQL 8.3.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.1-3ubuntu3) 4.4.1` (from `SELECT version()`).

My problem is when I update a record it shows a failed error. Is there any mistake in my query?

The query is:

```
UPDATE uac_institution_view SET status = '2' WHERE nid = '9950'
```

and the error is:

```
failed : ERROR: infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "uac_institution_view"
```

I am new in this db. Can any one help me how to update a view?

Comment: I'm confused; didn't you post this before? I don't see it in your post history, but I've seen this *exact* question before. Yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13151566/398670 . Is this you: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1119497/srinu?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13151381/398670, http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/944071-update-problem-postgresql-db, http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/how-to-update-a-view-933254.html . Are these your posts too? They're all recent and all much the same. If you aren't @srinu, did you search before posting?

Answer (score 1):

A view is just that: a different way of looking at something else.

Don't update the view; update whatever table(s) the view is based at. (See also [Cannot update view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151566/cannot-update-view?rq=1))

Comment: thank you, your link helped me.

Comment: Do you realize that the link is to a question pretty much identical to this one, **asked by you?**

Comment: no sir actually two members are working on this,so they also ask same question to you.

Comment: by using joins we can update a view.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Exactly how does one use a join to update a view?

Comment: there is a common field in parent table and view so by using left join i updated the view.i use the following query to update view       $query = "select a.nid,a.status,a.editiontitle,a.uac_edition_details_editiontype,b.title from uac_institution_view as a LEFT JOIN node as b on b.nid = a.nid where a.status='1' order by a.uac_edition_details_editiontype asc, a.editiontitle asc, a.title asc";