# Create and Update a SQL view concurrently?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Is it possible to create and update a SQL view at the same time? I'm using pgAdmin3 and I have to update five values of a row inside a view. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You simply cannot update view value, as the values are stored in table and you need to update table.

Comment: Possibly, your question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151566/cannot-update-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151566/cannot-update-view)

Comment: You can update a view if it is simple enough to be [auto-updatable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS) or if you use INSTEAD OF triggers that maps your UPDATE to the real tables.